# Seed a has_and_belongs_to_many table relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project with 2 models linked through a **habtm** relationship and 
would like to seed the default relationships values as they are fixed and needed for the 
web aplication to work.

Can't seem to find a way to access the model join table and seed the default values to the object1_id, object2_id as the table is not linked to a model. It's currently being done via SQL directly on postgreSQL.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to generate a join table if you have not already done so:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTable users roles
```

And as long as you have habtm in their respective classes:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end
```

Just push the object you are creating onto the associative array:

```
# db/seeds.rb
bill = User.create(name: "bill")

bill.roles << Role.create(title: "admin")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can think of any place where you would want to access the model directly, create the model. Otherwise direct sql query is probably fine.